# AUTORECODE from SPSS to R

Tags: r, spss

I want to write a function that is doing the same as the SPSS command AUTORECODE.

AUTORECODE recodes the values of string and numeric variables to consecutive integers and puts the recoded values into a new variable called a target variable.

At first I tried this way:

```
AUTORECODE <- function(variable = NULL){
    A <- sort(unique(variable))
    B <- seq(1:length(unique(variable)))
    REC <- Recode(var = variable, recodes = "A = B")
    return(REC)
}
```

But this causes an error. I think the problem is caused by the committal of A and B to the recodes argument. Thats why I tried

```
eval(parse(text = paste("REC <- Recode(var = variable, recodes = 'c(",A,") = c(",B,")')")))
```

within the function. But this isn´t the right solution.

Ideas?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, isn't this what `factor` does?

Comment: @James: `as.numeric(factor(.))` to get the actual integers, but yes.

Comment: Factor is giving back unique values from the variable as levels. The function should return levels, starting from 1.

Comment: oh thanks! as.numeric is the solution!

Comment: @Aaron @Diegoal If you use `str` or `print.default` on a factor, you can see that it actually stores these numbers, but the methods for objects of class factor tend to display the level names.

Comment: @James, yes, good point.  Diegoal: I do wonder what the purpose is; this feels like perhaps you're asking this while trying to replicate some other R functionality.  That is to say, more context in your questions can result in vastly more helpful answers.

Comment: @Aaron you could put your comment in an answer, I could also do that, but this way you will get any rep ;).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: I suppose that would be good form for someone to do that.  I don't really need the rep, and a good answer has more explanation than our brief comments, so I was trying to avoid the extra work.  But as I'm lower rep than either you or James, I'll write something out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`factor` may be simply what you need, as James suggested in a comment, it's storing them as integers behind the scenes (as seen by `str`) and just outputting the corresponding labels.  This may also be very useful as R has lots of commands for working with factors appropriately, such as when fitting linear models, it makes all the "dummy" variables for you.

```
> x <- LETTERS[c(4,2,3,1,3)]
> f <- factor(x)
> f
[1] D B C A C
Levels: A B C D   

> str(f)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 4 2 3 1 3
```

If you do just need the numbers, use `as.integer` on the factor.

```
> n <- as.integer(f)
> n
[1] 4 2 3 1 3
```

An alternate solution is to use `match`, but if you're starting with floating-point numbers, watch out for floating-point traps.  `factor` converts everything to characters first, which effectively rounds floating-point numbers to a certain number of digits, making floating-point traps less of a concern.

```
> match(x, sort(unique(x)))
[1] 4 2 3 1 3
```